# sql - Mysql : Left join on multiple rows and retrieve 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables:

Table : Movies

```
MovieID -- Name
1          -- Movie1
2          -- Movie2
```

Table: Types

```
MovieID -- Type
1          -- DVD
1          -- Bluray
1          -- VCD
2          -- DVD
```

I need a query to find out this in one row:
Movie1 : DVD - Bluray - VCD

I used:

```
SELECT Movies.Name,
IF(TYPE = 'DVD', 1, 0 ) AS DVD,
IF(TYPE = 'Bluray', 1, 0 ) AS Bluray,
IF(TYPE = 'VCD', 1, 0 ) AS VCD
FROM Movies LEFT JOIN Types ON Movies.MovieID = Types.MovieID
```

But it return multiplate lines:

```
Movies.Name -- DVD -- Bluray -- VCD
Movie1          -- 1     -- 0        -- 0
Movie1          -- 0     -- 1        -- 0
Movie1          -- 0     -- 0        -- 1
Movie2          -- 1     -- 0        -- 0
```

I want:

```
Movie1          -- 1     -- 1        -- 1
Movie2          -- 1     -- 0        -- 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [**`group_concat()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function might do the trick, here.

Not tested, but I suppose something like this should work :

```
SELECT Movies.Name,
    group_concat(type separator ' - ') as type
FROM Movies 
    LEFT JOIN Types ON Movies.MovieID = Types.MovieID
group by Movies.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want separate columns returned for each type:

```
SELECT m.Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Type = 'DVD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DVD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Type = 'Bluray' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bluray,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.Type = 'VCD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VCD
    FROM Movies m
        LEFT JOIN Types t 
            ON m.MovieID = t.MovieID
    GROUP BY m.Name
```

Comment: I really like this way of getting additional data from joined rows - it's reasonably fast and you can have conditions on joined records value by using HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.Name,
IF(t1.Type IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as DVD,
IF(t2.Type IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as Bluray,
IF(t3.Type IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as VCD
FROM Movies m
LEFT OUTER JOIN Types t1 on m.MovieID = t1.MovieID and t1.Type = 'DVD'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Types t2 on m.MovieID = t2.MovieID and t2.Type = 'Bluray'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Types t3 on m.MovieID = t3.MovieID and t3.Type = 'VCD'
```